# Selection sort program not sorting correctly

Tags: c++, selection-sort

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, arr[10], i, j, temp, minin;
    cin >> n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        minin = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] < arr[minin])
                minin = j;
            temp = arr[minin];
            arr[minin] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are no compile-time errors. But my code does not sort properly.

This is what I get:

**INPUT :**

```
4 //size of the array to be sorted
5 3 2 8 //actual array to be sorted
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
3528
```

The expected output is the sorted array in ascending order.

Comment: Please show the input and the incorrect output the program gives.

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions. The data-structures tag is also irrelevant.

Comment: Don't you need spaces or newlines between output elements?

Comment: *There are no compile-time errors. But my code does not sort properly.* -- I know you're probably new to programming, but there is one thing you should realize -- compiling with no errors does not mean the program is correct.  All that means is that there are no syntax errors -- it doesn't mean the program is logically correct.   If the program doesn't give the correct results, then it's time to debug your program.

Comment: Is there a good reason not to use `std::sort`.

Comment: Your program will fail, if n > 10.

Comment: @schorsch312: Yes, calling `std::sort` fails to give the student exercise in writing code and learning the language.

Comment: *Please mention the necessary alterations* -- Programming does not work this way. 
 If your program has a bug, and you wrote the code, you're responsible for initiating the process of debugging the code, not us or anyone else.  Learning how to debug your own code is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.  [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  Continuing to ask others to debug the code will lead to downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

Off the top of my head (no testing at all) you need to move the swap code out of the inner loop

Not your code

```
for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
{
    if(arr[j]<arr[minin])
        minin=j;
    temp=arr[minin];
    arr[minin]=arr[i];
    arr[i]=temp;
}
```

but instead

```
// calculate the index of the minimum element in the rest of the array
for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
{
    if(arr[j]<arr[minin])
       minin=j;
}
// swap the minimum element with the current element
temp=arr[minin];
arr[minin]=arr[i];
arr[i]=temp;
```

That is what you should do is calculate the minimum index first, and then swap the minimum index with `i`. These tasks should be separate, your code mixed them up.